# binary representation

Tags: c++

For example,sum(6) must return 2, because the binary version of 6 is 110

not sure the logic is correct or not.

```
int sum(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(n)
    {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
int main(){
    int n   =   9001;
    cout << “The    sum of  bits    for number  “   <<  n   <<  “is”    <<  sum(n)  <<  endl;
    retun   0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Unless you're looking for a complete answer that you can just copy and paste, I don't see any question in here. What is it you're trying to ask?

Comment: your code is fine until you enter a negative number... then it will never stop.

Comment: I want to know whether it is ugly solution or not. If it is then i want to make sure I could write the good solution.

Answer (score 5):

As ever, the best way to tackle these problems is to use the standard library. You have all studied the tools available in the standard library, right?

;-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>


template<class T>
size_t bits_in(T t)
{
    return std::bitset<sizeof(t) * 8>(t).count();
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int i = 6;

    cout << "bits in " << i << " : " << bits_in(i) << endl;

    long l = 6353737;
    cout << "bits in " << l << " : " << bits_in(l) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
bits in 6 : 2
bits in 6353737 : 11
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int sum(int n)
{
  int count = 0;
  if (0 != n)
  {
    while(++count, n &= (n - 1));
  }
  return count;
}
```

is fast because it only loops once for each 1 bit.

Comment: this is a really nice solution if you know that the architecture does not have an instruction to count bits intrinsically (some do). The `std::bitset` solution allows the implementation to make use of these instructions so ought to be at least as fast, if not faster - assuming you're using a well-implemented library. +1 for the nice algo.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using GCC as a compiler, checkout the builtin `__builtin_popcount()`. It returns the number of 1's in binary representation.

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for more info.

EDIT 2: I had an incorrect solution here, removed it. Thanks to comments for pointing it out.